# Importing babylon.js into simple webpack angular project

Tags: angularjs, webpack, babylonjs

Angular2-Webpack-Starter is a bit too much for my needs right now.  So I've created the angular webpack project as seen here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

I downloaded babylonjs with: npm install babylonjs.  From reading around, I get that this isn't a properly formatted package to simply import, but if I add it to vendor.ts it is bundled up in vendor.js:

```
import "babylonjs/babylon.max";
```

However when trying to use it, I get:

```
BABYLON is not defined
```

So I figure it must not be exported properly.  I've tried various ways to export BABYLON, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';
```